# MATLAB: Converting numeric values to NaN

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm trying to import an excel file containing latitude and longitude data into MATLAB. I'm using the 'Import Data' option. It is reading the latitude and longitude information just fine except that some of the longitude cells are being marked as unimportable and being replaced by `NaN`. They contain values like -119.253 etc. What could be the reason for this? I just want to keep the original information.

Below is a snapshot of a portion of my Excel spreadsheet:

[image: Excel Sample]

Comment: `xlsread` is an alternative, maybe it works. Please verify that your excel sheet contains numeric data and not text data. To verify this, you could add 1 or do a similar trivial calculation.

Comment: Yes, there is only numeric data in the sheet. It's reading the column fine except for some cells. Please follow the link for a screenshot. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32217906/prob.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot shows the Problem. All numbers that are left-alligned aren't real numbers, that is text. Numbers are alligned to the right.

Mark the column in excel and change the format to number.